# use GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport() func, return a error! java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, google-developer-tools, androidpublisher

This is my maven dependent libraries.

```
<groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-androidpublisher</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev20230615-2.0.0</version>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.43.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is code:

```
`InputStream purchaseToken = GoogleChannel.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxxxx.json");
            assert purchaseToken != null;
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(purchaseToken)
                    .createScoped(Sets.newHashSet(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));
            androidPublisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
                    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                    GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                    new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)).build();
```

but the error appears in the dependent library.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0t1.jpg)

Looking for a lot of methods, still reporting errors，I don't know what to do with it, please

Replaced different dependency versions, ended up using the latest version, but still got the error.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.